# Mysql sum value from different tables and calculate ratio then can calculate the growth rate of the ration

Tags: mysql

My question would be a little bit complicated.I have two tables, Table A and Table B

```
  Table A Structure
  ItemCode   Amount         DatebyDay
  01         500           20170814
  ...
  01         500           20170818
  01         1000           20170821
  ...
  01         1000           20170825
  ...

  Table B Structure
  FieldCode   Amount         DatebyDay
  fda        10000          20170814
  ...
  fda        10000          20170818
  fda        10000          20170821
  ...
  fda        10000          20170825
  fdb        10000          20170814
  ...
  fdb        10000          20170818
  fdb        10000          20170821
  ...
  fdb        10000          20170825
  ...
```

I would like to have SQL which could:

1. Sum every item's amount in tableA by week.
2. Sum amount of fda and fdb in tableB by week.
3. divide Step1 value with Step2 value to calculate the ratio at the same week

eg.

```
  sum(tableA.01AmountOfWk34)
/ (sum(tableB.fdaAmountOfWk34) + sum(tableB.fdbAmountOfWk34)).
```

4. divide the value got from step3 with the same result of the last week.

I want to evaluate the growth rate.

My expected result:

```
   WeekNum  ItemId  DividedResult                Times
   33         01     0.05  #(500*5)/(10000*5)      ..
   34         01     0.1   #(1000*5)/(10000*5)     2  # (0.1/0.05)
   34         02     ...                      
   34         03     ...
   35
```

I got help and wrote a sql can finish first 3 steps and don't how to finish Step4.

```
 SELECT Year(a.datebyday), WEEK(a.datebyday), a.itemcode,SUM(a.amount),SUM(b.amount),SUM(a.amount)/SUM(b.amount) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON b.code in ('fda','fdb') AND a.datebyday=b.datebyday GROUP BY Year(a.datebyday), WEEK(a.datebyday), a.itemcode;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the queries you have so far. When you have added the queries, please point out where in these queries do you have problems. Is it the grouping? The week calculation? The division? The reference back to the last week? The linking of table A and table B?...

Comment: My sql can finish first 3 steps and don't how to finish Step4.  SELECT Year(a.datebyday), WEEK(a.datebyday), a.itemcode, SUM(a.amount),SUM(b.amount),SUM(a.amount)/SUM(b.amount) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON b.code in ('fda','fdb') AND a.datebyday=b.datebyday GROUP BY Year(a.datebyday), WEEK(a.datebyday), a.itemcode

Comment: Edit your question to add your SQL query, don't add it as a comment.